# Theorems that hold in Euclidean and Elliptic Geometry but not in Hyperbolic (and vice versa)

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Question: Which theorems (if any) of plane Euclidean geometry continue to hold in Elliptic geometry but don't hold in Hyperbolic? And are there theorems that are valid in Euclidean and Hyperbolic geometries but not in Elliptic?

Basically, one would like to know those geometric properties for which Euclidean is a sort of  'limit of validity'.

Comment: "Sum of angles of a triangle is not less  (corr. is not more) than two right angles". I guess this does not count.

Comment: Thanks! one was actually looking for theorems older than this one :)

Comment: "For every line L and every point p not on L, there is at most one line L' through p and not meeting L." Does this count? It is not exactly a "theorem"...

Comment: What I was looking for was some Euclidean theorem (saying something more than the parallel postulate, like say, Napoleon's theorem) which continues to hold even in hyperbolic geometry but fails in elliptic - or vice versa.

Comment: @NandakumarR, a simply connected flat surface is noncompact..  This generalizes to hyperbolic geometry but fails for elliptic geometry.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give this as an answer with an example for the case "valid only for elliptical and euclidean" - plus (if possible), more examples for both cases? The example you gave seems to be a 'large scale' one; are there more 'local' examples - sorry if I am not precise there.